# Predicting a Target Variable in Different Units

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I have a target variable "Quantity". The values of this variable is such that it can be in different units in different rows. For example, the first row can be kg, fifth row can be dozens, hundredth row can be litres, and so on. Is it ok to build a Neural Network to predict this variable given that the values are in multiple scales?

Comment: No? How would the network possibly now what unit to predict? How would _you_ know what unit the network output is in?

Comment: @xdurch0 Agree, that is my intuition therefore I posted this question. I was wondering of there is some gap in my understanding of the neural network algorithm and the ANN may be able to understand the differences automatically.

Comment: Neural networks are simply function approximators. Mathematical formalisms. They are not magic and certainly not "intelligent". ;) I don't know if this was part of your question, but of course the solution here would be that you would need to convert all targets to the same unit beforehand.